# Redirect Out of Stock Product to custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I have a WooCommerce shop and I sell many products **with only 1 pieces for each**.

After selling the unique quantity product, I show **"Out of stock"** automatically but I want to redirect this Product page to a custom page.

I search many hours for a Plugin => Nothing.

Do you have an solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_before_single_product`** action hook, will allow you to redirect to your custom page, all products (pages) when product **is out of stock** using a simple conditional WC_product method [**`is_in_stock()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_is_in_stock), with this very compact and effective code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'product_out_of_stock_redirect');
function product_out_of_stock_redirect(){
    global $product;

    // Set HERE the ID of your custom page  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==
    $custom_page_id = 8; // But not a product page (see below)

    if (!$product->is_in_stock()){
        wp_redirect(get_permalink($custom_page_id));
        exit(); // Always after wp_redirect() to avoid an error
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> You will have just to set the correct page ID for the redirection *(not a product page)*.

---

**Update:** You can use the classic WordPress **`wp`** action hook *(if you get an error or a white page)*.

Here we need additionally to target the single product pages and also to get an instance of the **`$product`** object *(with the post ID)*.

So the code will be:

```
add_action('wp', 'product_out_of_stock_redirect');
function product_out_of_stock_redirect(){
    global $post;

    // Set HERE the ID of your custom page  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==
    $custom_page_id = 8;

    if(is_product()){ // Targeting single product pages only
        $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);// Getting an instance of product object
        if (!$product->is_in_stock()){
            wp_redirect(get_permalink($custom_page_id));
            exit(); // Always after wp_redirect() to avoid an error
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code detect "If is in Stock" properly but the redirection doesn't work. Stuck on blank page ...

Comment: @LionelF I have update my code with an alternative using  the classic **`'wp'`** wordpress action hook. This should work without problem this time. On the first snippet code you can get an error if the redirection is made on a product page.

Comment: Work perfectly now ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('wp', 'wh_custom_redirect');

function wh_custom_redirect() {
    //for product details page
    if (is_product()) {
        global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
        if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {
            wp_redirect('http://example.com'); //replace it with your URL
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!